# Is there a faster way to assess accuracy of image classification in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, accuracy, image-classification

I am trying to perform accuracy assessment on a raster RGB image after supervised classification. I know the normal workflow in ArcGIS would be to create accuracy assessment points, then evaluate each point with ground truth data and lastly to calculate the confusion matrix. But the visual evaluation of ~500 points to reference data is beyond time consuming.

Is there a faster way to do this?